# ASP.NET: How to enter a Tab character in entry of listbox?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list box which has a few itens as coded below in an aspx file:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1">   Chairs</asp:ListItem>
```

As you can see, I tried to put a few blank characters before the word Chairs BUT they are removed when Chairs is displayed in the dropdown list box.

How do I force the indentation of Chairs with spaces or with a tab character in a aspx file? \t for TAB doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:ListItem Value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chairs</asp:ListItem>
```

Try the `&nbsp;` for the spaces which is the html representation of a space.

Comment: Marvelous! Thanks. I will check this as answer (system requires a wait of several minutes before allowing me to  do so).

Answer (score 2):

How about adding CSS styles to indent the text? You can set the `text-indent: 10px` CSS style on the `<option>` tag. Mind you, it won't work in IE, which sucks pretty bad.

Also don't forget the `<optgroup>` tag, which you can use to group elements in a dropdown. It's a very overlooked tag, probably because the ASP.NET list and dropdown controls doesn't support it.

Try this in your page, and see what happens:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group 1">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group X">
    <option value="1">Item A</option>
    <option value="2">Item B</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

:)